# How can I split two random numbers created with mt_rand()?

Tags: php, string

I currently have the following code below:

```
$akey = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand();
$bkey = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand();
$ckey =  $akey . $bkey;
```

If I have ONLY ckey, is there any way to divine akey and bkey from it (without knowing them already)?

I am scratching my head.  I believe mt_rand() could be 6 one time and 1bb3D the next.  I was thinking initially to use some way to split the string in half (50% on each side), but if the akey and bkey are different lengths then that won't work.

Can I pad each one first to ensure they're equal and THEN split?  And if so, how?  Or is there a better way to do this?

(Edit:  The purpose is to have a key made up of 2 other parts.  Three people will hold the parts: ckey or akey and bkey.  One person will have full control with ckey, whereas akey and bkey holders must depend on each other to access. I think actually there's no reason why it would have to be mt_rand() except it was working fine up to this point.  If there's another way to get a 30 char ckey and then halve it into akey and bkey, that's fine.  But nobody will know the other keys.  There do seem to be some functions out there though I don't know how to tell which are the most "random" or secure...)

Thank you!

Comment: Abandon this approach and just generate a randomized string of the required length. This is very well covered.  https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+generate+random+string&oq=php+generate+random+string&aqs=chrome..69i57.4567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Just don't concatenate.

Comment: If you were to tell us what its use is, we'd be able to help you out better and with different options; there are many.

Comment: If you generate them how come you don't know them already ?
$len = ''; while(strlen($len) != 10){ @$len .= rand(0,9); }

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you, I added the purpose.  I guess I DON'T need to use mt_rand...so meagar's comment is useful.  Hard to know what would be really random or secure though.  lonut, I don't know them because once they're generated they're not stored and this is for a specific reason.  But at a certain point, ckey's process needs to divine akey and bkey.

Comment: You're welcome. There are other functions you can use to assure uniqueness, or using a mix of. For instance, `uniqid()` is one. To assure uniqueness, I like to use that and in conjunction with a UNIX TIMESTAMP and maybe a dash of another random function. You can also look into `nonce`, but that's mostly used if you want to use a one-time key.

Comment: Thank you, Fred!  Would you be able to write that as an answer?  It sounds like it will work.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, @Fred, it uniqid has a big warning saying it's not particularly good for genuine randomness.  I want a fairly random scramble that provides lots of entropy.

Comment: As I said, I like using a mix of 2 functions, 3 at the most. `$rand = uniqid() . mt_rand() . time();` should give you plenty of uniqueness.

Comment: But can I ensure that the resulting $rand will be 40 (or 80 or 160) characters long each and every time?

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. Well, `int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max )` so you could simply take the number of chars from `uniqid()`, then compensate with the difference in changing to `mt_rand(5, 15)` for instance, since [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) takes/accepts 2 arguments.

Comment: If I did mt_rand(10000,99999) it would be forced to always give me a 5 digit number, right?  Maybe that's all I need to do for my purposes.

Comment: Sure, give it a try.